# Conditions for continuity of the map $x \mapsto \mu_x$ (where $ \mu = \intop \mu_x d \mu (x)$ is the ergodic decomposition of $\mu$)

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, weak-topology, polish-spaces

Let $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu,T)$ be a measure preserving system on a Borel space. Let $\{\mu_x\}_x$ be the conditional measures from the ergodic decomposition of $\mu$  (that is, $ \mu = \intop \mu_x d \mu (x)$ where $\mu$-a.e. x $\mu_x$ is invariant and ergodic). Consider the space of probability measures $\mathcal{P}(X)$ with the weak topology. Are there conditions under which the map  $x\mapsto\mu_x$ is continuous?

P.S.- I'm also interested in such results w.r.t some other topologies on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ rather than the weak topology (in particular topologies that induced by metrics, but not necessarily Lévy–Prokhorov metric).

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a comment than an answer (I can't comment due to insufficient reputation), but such continuity probably doesn't hold in general. For a silly family of counterexamples, let's say $\mu$ is a nontrivial convex combination of a finite number of ergodic measures, $\mu = \sum_{i=1}^n t_i \mu_i$. Then (as defined a.e. with respect to $\mu$, which is an issue in itself), the ergodic decomposition will be such that $\mu_x \in \{\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n\}$, which won't be continuous with any sensible topology on $\mathcal{M}_1(X)$ if $X$ is connected.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/2043647)

Comment: @amWhy I don't see where I'm asking for clarification from the asker in my answer.

Comment: Also, "are there conditions" questions are not well posed as mathematical statements. Unless the system is uniquely ergodic, then you will have plenty of invariant measures like the ones in my answer. But if it is uniquely ergodic, then the continuity is trivially true. Could you clarify why you think my answer doesn't help?